# why does a low value weight paint cause my mesh to move significantly?

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I've rigged my mesh with empty groups and as I've gone through I've noticed the weight painting values of my mesh don't really seem to matter. They move as if they have a paint of 1 or 0. The most egregious example I can find is the mesh I use for eye shading, with the bottom weight painted at 0.01 and the top at 0, it follow the bone eye_shadow_R like it's painted at 1. I've check the mesh is not painted to any other bones.

[image: Weight painting eye shade mesh to eye_shadow_R bone (right corner), the top is weighted 0 and the base at 0.01, 0.1, and 1 from the corners to the middle.]

I'm using blender4.0.2, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If your vertex is assigned to only one vertex group, it doesn't matter if the weight is 0.01 only, it will move 100% with the bone that controls this vertex group, as if its weight was 1. If your vertex is part of 2 vertex groups or more, the weight will be taken into account, for example if the vertex is part of vertex group A with a weight of 1 and part of vertex group B with a weight of 1 as well, the vertex will be 50/50 influenced by bones A and B, if it is part with of A with a weight of 0.1 and part of B with a weight of 1, it will be moved 10 times more by B, etc...

Comment: So to fix it, I'd have to paint it to multiple groups for he relative weighting to actually make a difference? What would you do if you didn't want a second bone then?

Comment: Yes you need to assign this vertex or these vertices to a new vertex group that will have its controller bone

Comment: That's part of why having a root bone is standard: you can "default" any unwanted weights to it.